# MVC Unrendering Script and Style files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 different layouts in my project that based on the view that is called, I will tell the view which layout to use.  I'm having an issue where my first layout is rendered (my landing page), I render a certain set of scripts/styles.  Once I want to render my 2nd layout, the browser is holding on to all the styles/scripts from my previous layout.  Is there anyway to decouple those scripts/styles when changing layouts?

Comment: are you using `@Section`'s to render the scripts, or are they in the layout directly?

Comment: @Juventus18 I'm using the layout.  I've never really used Sections, would that help my issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "the browser is holding on to..."?

Comment: @Haney meaning they are being cached and executed even though the layout I've loaded doesn't render them.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm dumb.  I forgot to change one of my script and style render strings.  Once I put the right one in it works.

Comment: For future reference, this site is a lot more helpful if you include some code that people can investigate. Otherwise it's all speculation. Glad it's worked out!